# Significance of EXTERNAL keyword while creating table in hive

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, amazon-emr

I have noticed one thing if you create an external table with **EXTERNAL** keyword pointing to some S3 bucket location. Data get loaded and you can query it. But, even if i don't use **EXTERNAL** keyword and use the rest of the script for creating the table. Even then it works perfectly. Why is it so? Also, is it a external table or interntal table? If, i delete this table will the metadata be deleted or data also? Is there any Significance of term **EXTERNAL**?

If i create a table with EXTERNAL keyword and location and another table without EXTERNAL keyword but with location. What is the difference, when i am getting the same behaviour?

```
create table dummy(id int, value string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '~'
    STORED AS TEXTFILE
    LOCATION 's3n://logs/july';

                 VS

create external table dummy(id int, value string)
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '~'
        STORED AS TEXTFILE
        LOCATION 's3n://logs/july';
```

Comment: @Tariq before downgrading just read the explanation before. I know the difference between external table and manage table.

Comment: I know i'm late, courtesy some busy schedule. First things first, downvote was not at all random. it was totally intentional. Had you tried it instead of just posting it here, you would have got the answer. There was absolutely no need to be hyper. Anyways, see the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use **Location** with a **managed** table, its purpose is to create a new directory dedicated to this table, which would otherwise go to the default location, **/user/hive/warehouse/**. So, when you do :

```
create table dummy(id int, value string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '~'
    STORED AS TEXTFILE
    LOCATION 's3n://logs/july';
```

It'll create a new directory called **s3n://logs/july** for the table **dummy** instead of creating a directory **dummy** inside **/user/hive/warehouse/**.

Same thing will happen if you use **Location** with an **external** table for a **non-existing** location. While creating an **external** table if you give a directory location which exists then all the files inside this directory will collectively constitute the data of this table. And if the directory does not exists, then you'll see the same behavior as with managed tables, i.e. table will get created with a blank directory at the location same as the location specified by you while issuing the create command. Say, you do :

```
create external table dummy(id int, value string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '~'
        STORED AS TEXTFILE
        LOCATION 's3n://logs/july';
```

If **s3n://logs/july** exists then the table **dummy** will get created having data form the files present under **s3n://logs/july**. If **s3n://logs/july** doesn't exist then immediately after issuing the create command you'll see a brand new directory at this very same location. And if you delete this table, the directory **s3n://logs/july** will remain as it is, blank though(because you had pointed it to a non-existing location while table creation).

If you delete a **managed** table, even if it was created with **Location** clause the directory represented by Location will get **deleted**. I don't know how you are getting same behavior in both the cases. Try this and let me know what do you observe.

> BTW, SO is a place to share knowledge and thoughts with spirit. And
>   not to get hyper or to take stuff personally. If you disagree with somehitng, there is a proper way to put your point. And if it was just about a downvote, just let me know. I'll upvote all your questions and
>   answers.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. I said the same behavior thing because i first created table with EXTERNAL keyword 
and Location clause and data was loaded in the table from s3 bucket(s3n://logs/july). Then, i created table without 
EXTERNAL keyword but with Location clause still data was loaded which i didn't expect. I thought it will try to 
find PATH(s3n://logs/july) in the hdfs. Which won't be there. Hence, nothing will be loaded.

Comment: Well, first of all i apologise. But in the past also i have seen
you downvoted a person just because he didn't have the enough reputation(50 points) to comment on a question. 
So, he used the answer window to put his point. Instead of downvoting you could'have told him using comment. And please
don't embarrass a person asking to upvote after downvoting. Either at first place don't do it or do the upvote 
without asking. When it's "JUST ABOUT A DOWNVOTE" why do you dislike people who downvote you.

Comment: You are welcome. And there is absolutely no need to apologise. This is what I have learned over time as a SO user. I really appreciate the standard maintained by folks at SO and try to contribute to it. These are the things which make SO a beautiful place to learn and share. In the process we sometimes have to be a bit strict but that doesn't mean that I have any grudge against you or Arijit banarjee or anybody else. I had faced these things when I was new to SO and never complained about it like this as I respect the way SO works. But it's totally upto an individual.

Comment: I rarely down vote a question or answer. But posting a comment on the answer section is totally illogical, IMHO. That's why I had downvoted that question. And if I downvote somebody's question/answer that doesn't make me any superior to him/her. I'm still a learner and will always be. Downvoting is just a way to say that I do not agree with your point. When I asked you about upvotes it was not to embarrass you, I really meant it. If you are so much concerned about a downvote how can you learn?And I dislike people who downvote without even leaving a comment. How would I know about my mistake?

Comment: If you find something which deserves a downvote please go ahead and downvote my answers/questions. I would love to hear your comments. Anyways, since I firmly believe in rules of SO, i'm not gonna extend this comment game anymore. Long story short, it was nothing personal. I felt that it deserved a downvote, so I did it. And, please do not apologise to a person like me who is still a noob and trying to learn. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

External means Folder path is not part of hive warehouse (`/usr/hive/warehouse`).

when you use Drop command, external table drops only schema,
where as managed table even drops the data.

External table is useful for having daily transnational data as part of sql query output without any extra effort.

[read this also](http://pyfunc.blogspot.in/2012/03/external-tables-in-hive-are-handy.html)

Comment: But then if i use LOCATION keyword and don't use the EXTERNAL keyword. Is it a external table or internal table? Will it drop schema or data also if i drop this table?

Comment: by default it is managed (internal) table,in that case it will drop schema and data both

Comment: if, it is managed table and data will be deleted, If i drop the table, clearly denoted data is in hdfs. But, i am just using the location of data then how come it got into HDFS?

Comment: hive moves the data into warehouse that is hdfs ,i didnt get your question

Comment: my question is if i create a table with EXTERNAL keyword and location   and another table without EXTERNAL keyword but with location. What is the difference?

Comment: If you read that link one hdfs path can be used for both hive and any hadoop related technology if it is external table. and managed table data is moved to inetrnal warehouse.external tables avoids loading new data into warehouse .whatever data comes to hdfs path will be automatically added to table.